# Merge loop and print statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
items = [ "Abby","Brenda","Cindy","Diddy" ]

for item in items:
    print(item)
```

I use to write this statement for output items.

Is there a way to merge both print and loops. Something like:

```
print(item for item in items)
```

Correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [argument unpacking operator `*`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (also called the "splat" operator):

```
>>> items = [ "Abby","Brenda","Cindy","Diddy" ]
>>> print(*items, sep='\n')
Abby
Brenda
Cindy
Diddy
>>>
```

You need to set `sep='\n'` too because `print` defaults to separating arguments with spaces.

---

Just for completeness, when you do:

```
print(item for item in items)
```

It will create a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) over the items in `items` and then print that:

```
>>> items = [ "Abby","Brenda","Cindy","Diddy" ]
>>> print(item for item in items)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x5ffffe02ee08>
>>>
```

---

If you want to use this in Python 2.x, you will need to import `print_function` from the [`__future__` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) first:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> 
>>> items = [ "Abby","Brenda","Cindy","Diddy" ]
>>> print(*items, sep='\n')
Abby
Brenda
Cindy
Diddy
>>>
```

Comment: I know this is tagged for python 3.x but should also add a comment that this does not work in python 2.x

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension:

```
items = ["Abby", "Brenda", "Cindy", "Daddy"]
[print(item) for item in items]
```

And. . . you only need to add two characters to your code!

There is a good discussion about list comprehension versus generator expressions here:

[Generator Expressions vs. List Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension)

I think either is valid.  A genexp may be more efficient in this case, but the listcomp more clearly documents what you are doing.